# How to disable/Manage Accessibility announcement on ImageView? Android

Tags: android, imageview, accessibility, android-imageview, talkback

My Screen has Image and Titleview. I need to announce talkback as the Title text when the page loads. But it always announces the contentDescription of an ImageView.

**View Hierarichy**

ImageView and then title.

**What I tried ?**

Tried to set focus on title,
For that I set these attributes to ***ImageView***

```
android:focusable="false"
android:accessibilityTraversalAfter="@id/title"
android:importantForAccessibility="no"
```

Bad luck, none of these worked in my case. As a second try, I added these in my fragment

```
onResume {

    if (accessibilityManager?.isEnabled == true) {
        activity.title = title
        activity.window.decorView.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED)
    }
}
```

Still not working !! Does contentDescription of an ImageView has this much power?

I need to announce the **title** text when the page loads and if the user taps (or swipe left/right)then Imageview description needs to announce

**XML**
....

```
<data>
```

.....

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/vertical_padding"
    android:theme="@style/CL.Theme.Light">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/close_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_close"
        android:importantForAccessibility="no"
        android:contentDescription="CLOSE"
        android:accessibilityTraversalAfter="@id/title"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/back_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="BACK"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_back"
        android:importantForAccessibility="no"
        android:accessibilityTraversalAfter="@id/title
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/icon_margin"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/back_button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/primary_button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|clip_horizontal"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/horizontal_padding"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/error_screen_top_offset"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/horizontal_padding"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/vertical_padding">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="HEADER TITLE"
                android:focusable="true" 
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:importantForAccessibility="yes"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_goneMarginTop="62dp"
                tools:text="Title" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/subtitle
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/subtitle_margin_top"
                android:gravity="center"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title"
                tools:text="Subtitle" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/cta_margin_top"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/horizontal_padding"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/horizontal_padding"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/secondary_cta_margin"
    />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/horizontal_padding"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/horizontal_padding"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Could you share example of the xml layout?

Comment: @sigute Added XML layout.  ImageViews are close_button and back_button. Talkback Announce the content Description of it

Comment: Swapping views in xml might work, declaring NestedScrollView first, and then buttons underneath... But have you considered using a Toolbar instead of trying to make your own? :) It would have the behaviour you are trying to achieve by default.

Comment: @sigute I tried swapping views, but it didn't work. this is a dialog fragment. toolbar is not a option in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found better solutions from a different StackOverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61626024/samsung-s10-accessibility-view-focus-issues-with-talkback-on)

Hope this is able to help anyone else facing a similar issue.

```
fun View?.requestAccessibilityFocus(): View? {
   this?.performAccessibilityAction(ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS, null)
   this?.sendAccessibilityEvent(TYPE_VIEW_SELECTED)
   return this
}
```